# How to ensure that "document.body.appendChild(flash_object)" is loaded before the next line?

Tags: javascript, flash

Is there any way I can ensure that the Flash process is loaded before I call foo()?

```
window.onload = function (){
    document.body.appendChild(CreateFlashObject("flash_obj"));
    foo();
}
function CreateFlashObject(objectName){
    var obj = document.createElement("object");
    obj.setAttribute("id", objectName);
    obj.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
}
function foo(){
    //doing something with the flash_obj
}
```

Comment: I don't think `appendChild` is asynchronous. Any reason to believe it is?

Comment: Also, why don't you just pass the node to `foo` - that way you don't need to look it up.

Comment: I am actually not sure about appendChild but I think document.createElement is asynchronous though?

Comment: I would still need to make sure that the node is loaded right?

Comment: None of those are asynchronous; they have return values.

Comment: Okay, I guess I simplified my question too much. That object is actually a Flash object and I want to know when the Flash process is actually created.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the newly created html element to the foo function. It doesn't even need to be loaded for you to make changes to it.

```js
window.onload = function (){
    var obj = CreateObject("foo_obj1");
    var obj2 = CreateObject("foo_obj2");
    document.body.appendChild(obj);
    boo();
    foo(obj2);
    document.body.appendChild(obj2);
    console.log(obj,obj2);
}
function CreateObject(objectName){
    var obj = document.createElement("object");
    obj.setAttribute("id", objectName);
    return obj;
}
function foo(obj){
    obj.width = 400;
    obj.height = 400;
}
function boo() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("foo_obj1");
    obj.width = 200;
    obj.height = 200;
}
```